# TP-Link AC1200 USB WiFi Adapter Randomly Loses Connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb

I recently started using a new WiFi adapter from TP-Link (AC1200) for my gaming desktop build because my old PCIe based one started to cause A/V interference while running. The good news is all of my A/V issues went away, however I am experiencing a new problem. When I am not running any network demanding applications such as using the internet browser or playing an online game I randomly lose connection to my network. After I lose the connection nothing will allow me to reconnect to my network until I restart my computer at which point everything works fine until I stop using the internet and get disconnected automatically again.

Has anybody else experienced an issue like this with a USB WiFi adapter from TP-Link and found a fix for the annoyance?

Note: I am running the most current driver version for the WiFi card that Windows recommends.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your computer is powering off your usb-adapter, and can't turn it on again!

Have You checked the power settings of your usb-adapter?

Disable the setting "the computer can power off..."

also check the advanced power settings for usb selective power off...